# Component duplicating when using keys

Tags: reactjs, carousel, codesandbox, framer-motion

I am attempting to make a component carousel in React using Framer Motion. The children of `AnimatePresence` need a key, so I decided to pass a page state as the key. However, doing this makes the component I am trying to render duplicate. I thought it was because the key would eventually be re-used, so I made a function that generates a random string to use as the key, but that duplicates the component as well.

Component using carousel

```
const ProjectList = props => {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const projects = [
    <Project 
      name="Example"
      desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet."
      image={require("../img/exampleproject.png")}
    />,
    <Project 
      name="Example2"
      desc="Another example. This one does nothing too. What a suprise!"
      image={require("../img/exampleproject.png")}
    />
  ]

  const genKey = () => {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  }

  const paginate = (newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage)
  }

  return (
    
    <div className="project-list">
      <AnimatePresence>
        <motion.button key={genKey()} onClick={() => paginate(page-1)}>
          <ArrowBackIosIcon/>
        </motion.button>
        <motion.div key={genKey()} className="project-list"
          initial={{opacity: 0}}
          animate={{opacity: 1}}
          exit={{opacity: 0}}
        >
          {projects[page]}
        </motion.div>
        <motion.button key={genKey()} onClick={() => paginate(page+1)}>
          <ArrowForwardIosIcon/>
        </motion.button>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
```

I'm not sure how to use libraries like Framer Motion in the snippet editor, so I put it on CodeSandbox

[image: Edit priceless-sammet-9w1t3]

When I don't use a key, it works as expected, however whenever I click one of the arrow buttons it throws the following warnings

[image: warnings]

P.S I know eventually the page value will go out of range of the length of `projects`, I plan on fixing that once I can get this problem sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you do not need any key here.
Adding key (and moreover adding random keys -as you did with the `Math.random()` method) for elements that react manage will override the react pre-defined keys and could lead your program to kind of rendering bugs as you got here.

Keys are needed only when you generate components from an array (with the map function for example).

From the [doc](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) :

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements **inside the array to give the elements a stable identity**:

Here you do not need that.

Also a key must be the same for every rendering, and here you generate a random key (from the math random method each time you render this component).

Now since you are using this library : https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#usage

It precised that you have to use a key. The problem here is that you must give a constant keys. So remove the Math Random function and give some constant string as I did here :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Section from "./Section.js";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import Project from "./Project.js";
import ArrowBackIosIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos";
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos";

const ProjectList = props => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const projects = [
    <Project
      name="Example"
      desc="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet."
      image={
        "https://i.picsum.photos/id/928/600/300.jpg?hmac=ai-33AKRXhJnTcm88ArxRypuNNrfztMdJ-ui_8dhe8c"
      }
    />,
    <Project
      name="Example2"
      desc="Another example. This one does nothing too. What a suprise!"
      image={
        "https://i.picsum.photos/id/258/600/300.jpg?hmac=d-pTq52drP8dj3vsxB72sOgifDUNcookREV33ffONbw"
      }
    />
  ];



  const paginate = newPage => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  return (
    <div className="project-list">
      <AnimatePresence>
        <motion.button key="img1" onClick={() => paginate(page - 1)}>
          <ArrowBackIosIcon />
        </motion.button>
        <motion.div
          key="img2"
          className="project-list"
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        >
          {projects[page]}
        </motion.div>
        <motion.button key="img3" onClick={() => paginate(page + 1)}>
          <ArrowForwardIosIcon />
        </motion.button>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

Comment: The console throws a bunch of warnings when I don't use a key, sorry I should have mentioned that. Will this show up in prod? Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: Which kind of warning does it throws ? can you post them ?

Comment: @JordanBaron So i edit mine. Your problem is that you use the Random function which will generate a new key for each rendering (so the first time it will be rendered, element 1 will have the key "12345", and next time it will have the key "45678".React will not know how to render this. This will cause many rendering bugs. Use constant name or number istead as i did