# Why Mapping an Image in react-bootstrap show bug (duplicate output)

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to use mapping in react-bootstrap to show my image. I have 3 buttons and once this button is clicked by the user it will show different info and 4 different images. But in my case, once I clicked the button it will show 12 different images.
How can I fix this? Please help me.

Here's my Array Data:

```
const facsInfo = [
    {
        Id: "1",
        Title: "De'Spa",
        Description: "",
        upperleftimg:"./Images/DeSpa1.jpg",
        upperrightimg:"./Images/DeSpa1.jpg",
        bottomleftimg:"./Images/DeSpa1.jpg",
        bottomrightimg:"./Images/DeSpa1.jpg",
    },
    {
        Id: "2",
        Title: "De'Resto",
        Description:" ",
        upperleftimg:"./Images/DeResto1.jpg",
        upperrightimg:"./Images/DeResto2.jpg",
        bottomleftimg:"./Images/DeResto3.jpg",
        bottomrightimg:"./Images/DeResto4.jpg",
    },
    {
        Id: "3",
        Title: "Meeting Room",
        Description: "",
        Opentime:"Opening hours: 10.00 am – 8.00 pm",
        upperleftimg:"./Images/Room1.jpg",
        upperrightimg:"./Images/Room2.jpg",
        bottomleftimg:"./Images/Room3.jpg",
        bottomrightimg:"./Images/Room4.jpg",
    },
]
```

Here's my Facilities.JS Code:

```
const Facilities = () => {
    const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("1");

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(currentId);
    }, [currentId]);
  
    const showSelectedFact = () => {
      var fac = facsInfo.filter((x) => x.Id === currentId)[0];
      const { Title, Description, Opentime, Id } = fac;
      return (
        <div key={Id}>
          <h1 className="fontSB">{Title}</h1>
          <p>{Description}</p><br></br>
          <p><b>{Opentime}</b></p>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const showSelectedUpperImage = () => {
        var fac = facsInfo.filter((x) => x.Id === currentId)[0];
        const { upperleftimg, upperrightimg, Id } = fac;
        return (
            <>
                <Col key={Id} className="facsImage text-center" md={12} lg={6}>
                    <img className="img-fluid" src={upperleftimg}></img>
                </Col>

                <Col key={Id} className="facsImage text-center" md={12} lg={6}>
                    <img className="img-fluid" src={upperrightimg}></img>
                </Col>
            </>
        );
      };


      const showSelectedBottomImage = () => {
        var fac = facsInfo.filter((x) => x.Id === currentId)[0];
        const { bottomleftimg, bottomrightimg, Id } = fac;
        return (
            <>
                <Col key={Id} className="facsImage text-center" sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
                    <img className="img-fluid" src={bottomleftimg}></img>
                </Col>

                <Col key={Id} className="facsImage text-center" sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
                    <img className="img-fluid" src={bottomrightimg}></img>
                </Col>
            </>
        );
      };  

    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="facsbuttwrapper text-center">
                    <Col sm={4} lg={4}>
                        <Button
                        value="1"
                        variant="custom"
                        onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
                        >
                        De'Spa
                        </Button>
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={4} lg={4}>
                        <Button
                        value="2"
                        variant="custom"
                        onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
                        >
                        De'Resto
                        </Button>
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={4} lg={4}>
                        <Button
                        value="3"
                        variant="custom"
                        onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
                        >
                        Meeting Room
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="facsDetail fontReg">
                    <Col className="text-center" md={12} lg={12}>
                        {showSelectedFact()}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    {showSelectedUpperImage()}
                </Row>
            </Container>

            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    {showSelectedBottomImage()}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Facilities
```

Comment: Perhaps you could reproduce this code into a *running* codesandbox; I don't see any overt issue that would cause more than 4 images to render at a time in the specific code snippet you shared. Is `Facilities` rendered multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the use of `key` prop in the `Col` is causing the unexpected behavior, due to all the keys are being same. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209616/component-duplicating-when-using-keys) is some explanation of when to use the `keys` in the code and react [docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for `keys`.

Once I removed the keys from `Col` and `div`, all the code is rendering results without duplicate. [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/forked-demo-iy88y?file=/src/App.js) based on your code.